# Door to vacuum on the ISS

Tags: iss, airlock

Provided I had superhuman strength and the ability to open a door even with one atmosphere working against me, are there any singular doors or windows on the ISS which I could open directly to vacuum?

I don't want to have to open two doors so the airlocks are out (assuming they are kept pressurized when not in use).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure (although you might have to open other hatches to get to them)

The hatches in the PMAs connected to Node 2 if no visiting vehicle there, and the unused CBM hatch on Node 2.

[image]

The unused CBM hatches in Node 3.

[image]

The unused CBM hatch in Node 1

[image]

Probably Russian-side stuff too.

Source: Flying around in [DOUG](https://vrlab.jsc.nasa.gov/doug/download/) and looking.

Comment: One hopes that 'superhuman strength' would be needed to overcome not only 1 atm pressure but any number of safety interlocks!

Comment: Are the hatches sealed under pressure, or do they have locking mechanisms?

Comment: @Intellex actually just go here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13799/how-are-hatches-set-up-in-the-common-berthing-mechanism-cbm

Comment: To my knowledge, there are no interlocks on the CBM hatches.  The air pressure alone on a hatch creates roughly 35,000 lbf keeping it closed.

Comment: @Tristan I agree.

Comment: @Tristan: The [plug door](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_door) taken to its logical conclusion.